# How to remove bold heading inside an ASP.net inline expression

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My code is below, I am simply trying to remove the bold from all the actual text inside the expression, while keeping the constants and variables in bold.

Is there another simpler way I could do this?

```
<b><%=name.Text%><%=If(inPlace.Checked, "", ", as well as the Role of " + CONST_SPECIAL + " for " + name.Text + ".")%></b>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add multiple opening/closing b tags. Make sure they only surround your constants and variables.

Comment: Yes, it's just string concatenation.  Just be careful about properly HTML Encoding your variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want but have you tried this?

```
<b><%=name.Text%></b><%=If(inPlace.Checked, "", ", as well as the Role of <b>" + CONST_SPECIAL + "</b> for <b>" + name.Text + "</b>.")%>
```

I would suggest you use span (or strong) instead since b isn't a tag anymore.